# Как изменить ввод через input с enter например на пробел?

Tags: python, input

Что-бы ввести что-либо через input, надо нажимать enter, как сделать чтобы надо было нажимать пробел или что либо другое вместо enter??? Язык - python

Comment: Через input - никак. Создать свой input, который будет останавливать ввод по пробелу.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так: цикл ожидает текст до нажатия пробела.

```
import keyboard


while keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
    text = input()
```